How to use convertPackageToLibrary function?
I'd like to understand when and how to use the function OpenModelica.Scripting.convertPackageToLibrary. I think the documentation on this is very sparse and I am not successful trying to use it in any way.
Creating my own libraries I normally create one big .mo file containing a package with all subpackages and models in this file (in contrast to organizing it by creating folders for every subpackage with package.mo files and package.order files by using the 'within ...;' expression in every .mo file).
I thought running the mentioned function in OMShell would create such a folder-structure with the corresponding .mo files but I already failed by giving the function the correct parameters.
I created a test case as follows:
package TestLibrary

package Subpackage1model Model1end Model1;end Subpackage1;

package Subpackage2model Model2end Model2;end Subpackage2;

end TestLibrary;

The .mo file containing this code is saved in my /home-directory (Ubuntu).
When I try this in OMShell:
loadFile("/home/roman/Modelica/TestLibrary.mo");convertPackageToLibrary(TestLibrary, Test, 0.0.1);

I get the following error message:

Error occurred building ASTSyntax Error[:1:0-1:22:writable]
Error: Parser error:Unexpected token near: convertPackageToLibrary (IDENT)

I also tried it with TestLibrary.mo and /home/roman/Modelica/TestLibrary.mo but no success.
Am I wrong in trying to use the function that way? Or am I missing some details?

I am no OpenModelica user, but in Dymola, I would just need to duplicate my package and tick or untick "Save content of package in one file". Is there something similar in OpenModelica?

Jepp, just checked. You can uncheck the option "Safe contents in one file" when creating a new package. But i still need it to convert my already existing libraries "organized" in one single file. A hint how to use the function would be great...like does the package i want to convert have to be located in the libraries folder of modelica?
